# Java Nested ArrayList returns Object

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, nested

I have a nested ArrayList

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MenuItem>> MenuList = ArrayList<ArrayList<MenuItem>>()
```

MenuItem is my class containing the item name and task(int). I'm using a few buttons to iterate through my Menu, and when I press the "enter" key I'd like to access the currently selected MenuItem.

The code is as following;

```
// enter button pressed
if(buttonStateEnter != lastButtonStateEnter){
   // changes
   // get current menu
   ArrayList currentMenuList = MenuList.get(currentMenu);

   // get menuItem obj
   Object test = currentMenuList.get(0);

   System.out.println(test.getClass());

   // get the task (int)
   //int changeTask = subNest.getTask();

   lastButtonStateEnter = buttonStateEnter;
   redraw = true;
}
```

I want to create MenuItem test rather than Object test, because I cannot access my methods this way. test.getClass() returns Class MenuItem. Putting MenuItem test in code compiles with the error

```
java.lang.Object cannot be converted to MenuItem
```

Comment: typecast your list to actual type

Comment: well, you do save `MenuList#get` in a rawtype, which basicly just works with the `Object`. You shouldn´t do it that way and rather make use of the generic

Comment: What is the MenuList?

Comment: MenuList is my Menu (containing multiple menus) Sorry, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<MenuItem> Menu = new ArrayList<MenuItem> ()` should help.

Or you must typecast it with `get` operation as following:
`(MenuItem)Menu.get(`

But the second option shall give you warning to make sure you are typecasting to the right type

Comment: Then best would be to declare it of **supermost** class if they are compatible with each other

Comment: Thank you! Typecasting fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
// enter button pressed
if(buttonStateEnter != lastButtonStateEnter) {
  // changes
  // get current menu
  ArrayList<MenuItem> currentMenuList = MenuList.get(currentMenu);

  // get menuItem obj
  MenuItem test = currentMenuList.get(0);

  System.out.println(test.getClass());

  // get the task (int)
  //int changeTask = subNest.getTask();

  lastButtonStateEnter = buttonStateEnter;
  redraw = true;
}
```

Comment: Would suggesting not being Implementation dependent when declaring variables.

Comment: MenuItem cannot be converted to java.util.List<MenuItem>

Answer (score -1):

```
// enter button pressed
if(buttonStateEnter != lastButtonStateEnter){
   // changes
   // get current menu
   ArrayList <MenuItem> currentMenuList = MenuList.get(currentMenu);

   // get menuItem obj
   MenuItem test = currentMenuList.get(0);

   System.out.println(test.getClass());

   // get the task (int)
   //int changeTask = subNest.getTask();

   lastButtonStateEnter = buttonStateEnter;
   redraw = true;
}

This should work...
```